# Dynamic sql in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

How can i create dynamic sql in oracle according to if else statements.For example;

```
sql:= 'select n from where a = p_a';
if p_b is not null then
sql:= 'select n from where a = p_a and b = p_b';
```

Comment: Heard of `execute immediate`?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want dynamic SQL when you can just do the following?

```
select n
from xx
where a = p_a and (b = p_b or p_b is null);
```

Comment: @Gondon thanks for aid but need me concatane sql query.This query is not working.

Comment: Maheswaran excuse me.I dont look up at again.I find different solution.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
CREATE TYPE t_emp AS OBJECT (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(20))
/
CREATE TYPE t_emplist AS TABLE OF t_emp
/

CREATE TABLE dept_new (id NUMBER, emps t_emplist)
    NESTED TABLE emps STORE AS emp_table;

INSERT INTO dept_new VALUES (
    10, 
    t_emplist(
        t_emp(1, 'SCOTT'),
        t_emp(2, 'BRUCE')));

DECLARE
    deptid NUMBER;
    ename  VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT d.id, e.name
        FROM dept_new d, TABLE(d.emps) e  -- not allowed in static SQL
                                          -- in PL/SQL
        WHERE e.id = 1'
        INTO deptid, ename;
END;
/
```

You can incorporate your own logic to construct your command according to the conditions you want
[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm)